# What is the best way for modifying web.config in SharePoint using code

Tags: sharepoint-2010

What is the best way for modifying web.config in SharePoint using code? I could use SPWebConfigModification or powershell.

Comment: Depends on usage, you can use PowerShell, I just wrote a blog post on [modifying web.config via powershell](http://gavinb.net/2011/06/13/disable-mobile-redirection-for-a-web-application-via-powershell/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do web.config modifications from VS 2010 code. See below code for sample of the same. I have implemented

```
            //Add tagMapping
            string modificationName = string.Format(@"add[@tagType='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor'][@mappedTagType='PeopleEditor.CustPeopleFind,{0}']", 
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
            SPWebConfigModification modification = new SPWebConfigModification //(modificationName, "configuration/system.web/pages/tagMapping");
            {
                Path = "configuration/system.web/pages/tagMapping",
                Name = modificationName,
                Value = string.Format(@"<add tagType=""Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor"" mappedTagType=""PeopleEditor.CustPeopleFind"" />"),
                Owner = ownerID,
                Sequence = 1,
                Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode                    
            };
            webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(modification);

            //Save changes
            webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();

            //Serialize and propagate changes across farm
            webApp.Update();

            //Create the persistent objects
            Common.CreatePersistentObjects(webApp);
```

But, I should also warne you, many SharePoint experts do not recommend modifications done to web.config through code.

All the best

-Vighnesh

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it using code, SPWebConfigModification will be a good choice because that will take care of web.config modifications across all front end web servers in your farm. Doing it via PowerShell is almost like modifying it manually which is discouraged practice for SharePoint enviornment.

If you are using FEATURES, you may want to put your code in Feature Receivers.

If declarative modifications serves your need, you may prefer that (over code approach) as well. Entries like SafeControl are natively supported by Feature framework which should be the first choice for such entries. Another variation of declarative modifications is via supplemental .config file as described below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460914.aspx